# How do I change the serializer that my multiprocessing.mangers.BaseManager subclass uses to cPickle?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, serialization

Using **Python 2.7**,

I am passing many large objects across processes using a manager derived from multiprocessing.managers. `BaseManager` and I would like to use `cPickle` as the serializer to save time; how can this be done? I see that the BaseManager initializer takes a `serializer` argument, but the only options appear to be `pickle` and `xmlrpclib`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can't strictly do what your asking.

In fact, there's a fork of multiprocessing, [pathos](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathos), written by the creators of an alternative to pickle, [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) - also because of the limited ability to control the serializer.

I would personally suggest you use ipython.parallel, as it seems more actively maintained.

See more details on this matter in this piece [Parallelism and Serialization](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of dill and pathos. Multiprocessing should use cPickle by default, so you should't have to do anything.

If your object doesn't searliize, you have two options: go to a fork of multiprocessing or some other parallel backend, or add methods to your class (i.e. reduce methods) that register how to serialize the object.